# Ударение в слове «баклер»

Tags: орфоэпия, заимствования

Как правильно говорить: бáклер или баклéр? Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словари не фиксируют, однако само слово "бáклер" проходит в разных контекстах.

И нет причин ему быть баклéром, он же англосакс, а не француз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И влияний никаких не претерпевал, будь он англо-американцем Баклером, безалкогольным голландским пивом, итальянским клубом или девонширской деревней,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

смотрим [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%20%28%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%29&title=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA&go=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8&ns0=1) и [тут](https://winestyle.ru/beer/buckler/).

В поисках исходного значения я набрела на фамилию Буклер (других вариантов этимологии не предоставлено):

> фамилия Буклер образована от аналогичного прозвища. Оно ведет свое
>   начало от английского слова **«buckler» - «небольшой круглый щит»,
>   «защита, прикрытие»**. Вероятно, прозвище относится к так называемым
>   «профессиональным» именованиям, содержащим указание на деятельность
>   основателя фамилии: он мог заниматься изготовлением доспехов, либо
>   быть военным. Хотя не исключено, что такое прозвище получил надежный и
>   ответственный человек.

О бáклере, опять же с непроставленным ударением, [подробно рассказано в  Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80) (куда я попала прямиком из фамилии):

> **Баклер** (нем. Faustschild, фр. boce, bocete, rondelle de poing, ит.
>   brochiero) — маленький, 20-40 см в диаметре (8-16 дюймов), чаще всего
>   металлический круглый щит. Был рассчитан, главным образом, в качестве
>   вспомогательного оружия с мечом или шпагой. Держался за ручку с
>   обратной стороны. Баклеры имели только одну рукоятку, которую воин
>   сжимал в кулаке, из-за чего их называли «кулачными щитами»...

Но есть и ещё источник - рассказ специалиста по истории оружия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Слушаем 12 секунд, с 2:20 по 2:32.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GO5KnUdwpY)

Таки ***бáклер***.